# .Net upload xml files up to 1gb end in error

Tags: c#, html, .net, file-upload

I have a application, where the user can upload xml files. Everything under 25mb is no problem, but when i try to upload my test file (117 mb), I get an error when the application is hosted.

Since I prepared the application like described in 1000 other posts, its working locally up to 2gb and also when hosted. But after upload i get "HTTP Error 503.0 - Service Unavailable".

[image: error]

When i log in again, the file is there but the error is inconvenienced.

web.config:

```
<security>
    <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
    </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

upload function:

```
[HttpPost]
[RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 1073741824)]
public IActionResult Upload(IFormFile file){

    if(file == null) return RedirectToAction("OnixIndex");

    string completePath = app_resources_path + file.FileName;
    using(FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(completePath))
    {
    file.CopyTo(fs);
    fs.Flush();
    }
```

startup.cs

```
services.Configure<FormOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
    options.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
    options.MultipartHeadersLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
});
```

Should i use a different way to upload the file? I tryed a stream, but without improvement. I there a different technology or nuget bib?

Answer (score 0):

could you please list system specs (Ram,Storage Type,Cpu Cores, .net version),
this error is mostly related to system specs not being able to handle the 1 gb file and you need to scale your system as mentioned in the following thread.
[503 Server Unavailable after user uploads many files. Is this an httpRuntime setting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70052188/503-server-unavailable-after-user-uploads-many-files-is-this-an-httpruntime-set)